# Using a For-loop to create multiple objects with incremental suffixes, then reading in .csv file to each new object (also with incremental suffixes)

Tags: r, for-loop, append, suffix

I've just started learning R so forgive me for my ignorance! I'm reading in lots of .csv files, each of which correlates to a different year (2010-2019). I then filter down the .csv files based on a variable within one of the columns (because the datasets are very large. Currently I am using the below code to do this and then repeating it for each year:

```
data_2010 <- data.table::fread("//Project/2010 data/2010 data.csv", select = c("date", "id", "type"))

data_b_2010 <- data_2010[which(data_2010$type=="ABC123")]

rm(data_2010)
```

What I would like to do is use a For-loop to create new object data_20xx for each year, and then read in the .csv files (and apply the filter of "type") for each year too.

I think I know how to create the objects in a For-loop but not entirely sure how I would also assign the .csv files and change the filepath string so it updates with each year (i.e. "//Project/2010 data/2010 data.csv" to "//Project/2011 data/2011 data.csv").

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Next time please provide a repoducible example so we can help you.

I would use `data.table` which contains specialized functions to do what you want.

```
library(data.table)
setwd("Project")
allfiles <- list.files(recursive = T, full.names = T)
allcsv <- allfiles[grepl(".csv", allfiles)]
data_list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(allcsv)) {
  print(paste(round(i/length(allcsv),2)))
  data_list[i] <- fread(allcsv[i])
}

data_list_filtered <- lapply(data_list, function(x) {
  y <- data.frame(x)
  return(y[which(y["type"]=="ABC123",)])
})
result <- rbindlist(data_list_filtered)
```

1. First, `list.files` will tell you all the files contained in your working dir by default.
2. Second, read each `csv` file into the `data_list` `list` using the fast and efficient `fread` function.
3. Third, do the filtering within a loop, as requested.
4. Fourth, use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to `rbind` all of these `data.table`'s.
5. Finally, if you are not familiar with the `data.table` syntax, you can run `setDF(result)` to convert your results back to a `data.frame`.

I strongly encourage you to learn the `data.table` syntax as it is quite powerful and efficient for tabular data manipulations. [These vignettes](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube/library/data.table/doc/index.html) will get you started.